# Embedding StyleSheet not working in Xamarin

Tags: css, xamarin

I'm trying to embed a StyleSheet .css in Xamarin.

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <StyleSheet Source="../Styles/stylemain.css"/>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

stylemain.css

```
ol, ul {
   margin-top: 0;
   margin-bottom: 10;
}
ul li
{
   margin:0
}
StackLayout.bor-radius4 img {
   width: auto;
   height: auto;
   border-radius: 4;
}
```

I have set up stylemain.css Build Action: `Embedded resource`

[image]

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <StyleSheet Source="../Styles/stylemain.css"/>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<ContentPage.Content>
   <StackLayout Padding="12" Margin="0,0,0,5" BackgroundColor="#fff" StyleClass="bor-radius4">
      <htmlLabel:HtmlLabel Text="{Binding ProductInfo.Contents}" HorizontalOptions="Start" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" FontFamily="{StaticResource QuicksandRegular}" FontSize="13" TextColor="#333"></htmlLabel:HtmlLabel>
   </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

However it doesn't get the settings in stylemain.css

[image]

What did I do wrong?

**Update**
-- using inline CSS

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
        <StyleSheet>
            <![CDATA[  
                 ^contentpage {  
                   background-color: aqua;  
                 } 
                .bor-radius4>htmllabel>img {
                    width: auto;
                    height: auto;
                    border-radius: 4;
                }
               ]]>
        </StyleSheet>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
```

It still doesn't work

Comment: Please specify whare, "HtmlLabel" comes from? Is it a Label with TextType="Html"?

Comment: Yes, I use HtmlLabelPlugin , [link](https://github.com/matteobortolazzo/HtmlLabelPlugin)

Comment: Try using using inline CSS.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I used inline CSS. But it still doesn't work `border-radius`. I have updated the above

Comment: You can try to use [Styling Xamarin.Forms apps using Cascading Style Sheets (CSS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/css/) to achieve this.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, it works with ^contentpage,... In my case. I want it to work for html tags (ul, li, ol, img,....) when I bind data of html data `{Binding ProductInfo.Contents}`. This it doesn't work?